# PDI - how to skip file that have already processed?

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

Look at my jobs and transformation below :

[image: Jobs]
[image: Transformation]

I want to process files from FTP and Shared folder. My team will put CSV files in there every day if there are a new one. Files in FTP and Shared Folder will hold until 7 days old before being removed.

My question is if last day I have already process A.csv, B.csv and then today I want process only C.csv without A.csv, B.csv even the file still in the same folder and I don't want move or delete file that have already processed. How I do that?

Comment: easy way is you can create one sub-folder at both places, once file process is finish move it to newly created folder so every-time when transformation runs it will find only new file.

Comment: how about do it without moving any files? is't possible?

Comment: in that case you have to put some extra logic(figure out logic).
like extract the file-name store in some table, then before starting the transformation check whether file name exist in table or not, if it is then skip the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better create one table and store the processed file name. Add step to check the file name exists in that table or not. if not exists then process the file otherwise skip the file

Comment: I like this logic. It work well for my case. Thank you. So, the transformation I made is first join between 2 data `CSV Input` and `Table Input` using `Merge Join` then put `Filter Row` for the condition that only process file where the filename are not exist in the table just like your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the files using "Process result filenames" step with the Action "Copy" along with System Timestamp[Get System Info step] (File Processed Timestamp) in the same directory and delete the original file. With this, you will be having the file in the same folder/directory and processed files will have the timestamp attached to it. In this case, even if you rerun the job processed files will not be picked for processing due to change in the file name.

Comment: `Working hard`'s solution is easier to maintain. You just have to make a dir to know if you have files to process. So simple that you can even automate it. And, as far as the computer is concerned, there is no difference in moving a file or renaming it.

Comment: okay, 'cause I can't move the files out to another folder, I will used `Working Hard` suggestion (for now) to create sub dir in that folder. Thanks guys but if there any other way to do it using transformation(hopefully by not moving any file or rename the file) it would really help me.